# apache mpm event-check current number of servers and threads

Tags: linux, centos, apache-2.4, mpm-event

I'm using apache MPM event on my centos server with these configs:

```
<IfModule event.c>
StartServers 8
ServerLimit 32
ThreadsPerChild 256
MaxRequestWorkers 8192
MaxConnectionsPerChild 10000
MinSpareThreads 125
MaxSpareThreads 250
ThreadLimit 256
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 2
MaxKeepAliveRequests 500
</IfModule>
```

now what I need is to check what number of servers and threads are currently created by apache. how can I check these values?

Answer (score 1):

You need [mod_status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) Apache module

Comment: it then shows the number of threads, but what about number of servers?